# Jquery image crop and upload

Tags: php, jquery, image, crop

I need some help with my issue.
Im using this script:

http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/image-upload-and-crop-with-jquery-and.html

But when i load a big image (ex: 1500px x 900px) the browser rezise the image automatically, putting a magnifier in the cursor.
And when i select a area, crop and upload this not crop my selected area but the real size area.

Some idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

had you tried to force the image to by re sized to fit the browser?
browsers re sizes the photo visually , so when you get the crop area you will crop the actual image not that one re sized by the browser , 
my simple solution: 
- re size your image to fit the browser 
- or disable the browser auto resize